# Is it possible to use a third-party remote with an Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, third-party

I was thinking about this earlier and thought I'd ask. Can third-party remotes be used with the Apple TV (any and all versions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. You can have your Apple TV learn the remote codes of any IR remote by going to **Settings > General > Remotes**. It will then ask you to hit buttons on your new remote corresponding to what it shows on screen.

Full instructions can be found at Apple's site: [Controlling Apple TV with a third-party remote control](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3296?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Logictech remotes can be programmed to work and you can just go pair remote in the above menu, bingo!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Logitech Harmony remote that I use with the ATV and my other equipment like receiver, tv and HDTV-box. Works fine.